# Problem with storing large numbers in mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using mysql db to save id's. It was working fine.

But now an id like this 10000000754987. Is stored as 1.0000000754987E+14. How I can I fix it.

The field is set to varchar 255 characters limit.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the insertion code, are you sure its a varchar field? What you see above is the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), it does not need fixing, it is correct ;)

Comment: Have you debugged your PHP and ensured that you are infact passing '10000000754987' instead of '1.0000000754987E+14' to the sql query?

Comment: Why are you using varchar to store these numbers?  Why not use bigint?  The range is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615 - should be plenty for you.  Then it's just a matter of formatting a number.

Comment: I second the BIGINT notion. Use those all the time playaaaa

Comment: If you're on a 32-bit instance of PHP, your 'int's will turn to scientific notation once you cross the threshold.. read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: @MoarCodePlz @Aleks G @Beto Frega I am not using BIGINT because some ids have letters and characters in them. So only i am using varchar. So any alternative...

Comment: Have put the value inside single quote like VALUES('10000000754987')? Sometimes it happens if value is not quoted.

Comment: @Josh it seems that id you provided is not string in PHP. Use strings for large numbers in PHP. @Janek is correct.

Comment: @Josh I believe you have a typo in question. 10000000754987 is not equal to 1.0000000754987E+14. The first number lacks a digit at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently using PHP to generate that ID.

Since you didn't mention what's exactly happening, I can only assume certain reasons for your database design.

First off, you could store that number as `bigint` and not `varchar`. It's an integer you're saving, I see no reason why you'd use varchar and inherently waste more space than needed.
`bigint` uses 8 bytes to store a number. That means that every number with more than 8 digits stored in varchar field would use more space than a `bigint` field that can store numbers up to 2^64.

Second, make sure you don't use any number formatting before sending the result of your calculation operation to the db. I copy/pasted the integer you posted (10000000754987) and php doesn't automatically convert it to scientific notation so my guess is that you have something else going on there in the background with that number generation - turn it off if possible and store the number in appropriate field type (bigint). It'd also be useful if you posted additional info about your app and what it does, because error isn't always where people thing it is.

Comment: I think it's a typo in question, actually the number is longer by one digit. We can see this because of `E+14`. If the first number is correct then scientific representation would be `E+13`. So these two numbers in question are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the numerical IDs have gotten too big for PHP/MySQL to handle.

Change the data type to `VARCHAR(36)` and CakePHP will now start using [UUIDs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1016/Using-UUIDs-as-Primary-Keys) instead of numerical IDs, you will have to do this on any foreign keys for this table too. This will prevent this problem from happening in the future.

Additionally, as it's varchar, it should work with your current IDs too..