# how to store huge int value in php,I store 13262075231096090737 in mysql ,but it show as 1.3262075231096E+19

Tags: php

I use php to store a very big int in mysql ,the value is 13262075231096090737 ,but I echo that value,it shows as 1.3262075231096E+19, when I store as varchar,it also show as 1.3262075231096E+19. I want to know how to store a very huge int in mysql??

Comment: [pos related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664640/problem-with-storing-large-numbers-in-mysql-db)

Comment: I want get value as php

Comment: it would, you just perform the functionality MySQL-side

Answer (score -1):

in your database change field type to 'text' instead of 'varchar'

Comment: I have change field to longtext,still the same problem

Comment: check the value in the database how does it stored, if it was stored normally then  you have to operate with it as string not integer if you want to print it .

Comment: I simply the problem, $msgId1 = '13262075231096090737';
        $msgId2 = 13262075231096090737; two values,msgid1 is correct,msgid2 is lost its precision.how to change msgid2 to string without lose its precision.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are experiencing is not to do with the storage of the BIGINT, but rather the displaying of that number in PHP.

See this post for examples using:

- number_format()
- sprintf()
- printf()

[Why is PHP printing my number in scientific notation, when I specified it as .000021?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471674/why-is-php-printing-my-number-in-scientific-notation-when-i-specified-it-as-00)

Comment: it not working for me .I have two values. $msgId1 = '13262075231096090737'; $msgId2 = 13262075231096090737; msgid1 is ok.but msgid2 is not collect,when it change to string ,it lose its precision.I want to know how to store msgid2 without lose its precision.

Comment: Why are you storing it as a string if it is a number?